# Boxes all over unity where text should be

Tags: unity

Boxes all over unity suddenly after logging in

[image: Pictuer 1]
It happened all of a sudden and all the applications and status bar started closing automatically.

Comment: Have you done anything recently that could of caused this (with graphics, fonts etc) - and what graphics and drivers are you using (you can edit in the relevant bit of `lspci -v` for that)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the *System language*? If so, change the language back to English and see if your language package is installed properly.

Can you login from the TTY (pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 on login screen)? If so, try

```
sudo apt-get unity-control-center
```

If this doesn't work, install with *fix broken* option

```
sudo apt-get -f unity-control-center
```

You could also try

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

which will pretty much reinstall Ubuntu.